# Remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

When app service which is part of vnet integration trying to upload the blob in a storage container which is also part of same network and it is protected by private end point.

We are getting following error.

Azure.RequestFailedExecption. The underlying connection was closed. Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed. Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException. the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation

We tried lowering TLS both web and storage. But nothing really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the issue description, you have configured the setup as outlined on this doc - [Use private endpoints for Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints) and validated that the App Service and the Storage account are configured to the same VNET.

Kindly add the following App Settings to the App Service.

WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER  168.63.129.16

WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL  1

See this doc [Access an Azure Storage Account having a Private endpoint via an App Service](https://azureossd.github.io/2020/07/25/Connecting-to-Storage-Account-having-a-Private-Endpoint/) for more info.

Also, just to highlight, IP-Based SSL isn't supported with private endpoints.

Ref: [Using Private Endpoints for App Service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-private-endpoint#limitations)